# Writing a seperation line without date

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I wrote a middleware logging the incoming/outgoing traffic and exceptions of my REST-Service with ASP.NET. My logger in use is NLog and I'd like to print a separation line between the calls to make them better visible. For this the line should be always visible.

Best case would be a single line without any date like:

> ==============================================
>
> 2019-07-11 16:02:29.7280|INFO|Request to XXX
>
> 2019-07-11 16:02:34.7781|ERROR|Catched exception: Baaaaad
>
> 2019-07-11 16:02:34.7781|INFO|Response: empty

The best solution so far I found is to write with the highest log level, but I don't want the line to appear as `fatal`. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Current logger config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false"
      internalLogLevel="Off" internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <targets>
    <target name="logconsole" xsi:type="Console" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: please post the config.XML of your NLOG logger. Usually you would configure the format there

Comment: @MongZhu Until now its the most basic config file. I added it

Comment: where does the date come from if you haven't specified it in the [target layout](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#layouts-and-layout-renderers)?

Comment: @MongZhu Its the default format for when there is no other specified

Comment: ahh, ok then try to use the link I posted in my comment and specify one that adds 2 newline characters at the end :)

Comment: that would be `${newline}`

Comment: @MongZhu But as far as I understand Id need to assign that format to an output or loglevel. I want all outputs and loglevel as they are, they are fine. I just need a way to put out a line without format like ``logger.Unformatted("MyMessage")``

Comment: you assign it to a target not the level. the level is defined in the rules. you could also make an own target just for empty lines and log it whenever you decide it is necessary. Sorry gotta catch my train. good luck

Comment: You mean two targets for the same file (or console) and one of them is without formatting?

Comment: that sounds like a good idea

Comment: Gonna try that, thank you

Comment: With some c# code you could create anything you want. When should the separator be printed? (Manual, between levels, between request etc)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do this:

```
logger.Info("Call Begin Header{0}==============================================", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Should output the following:

> 2019-07-11 16:02:29.7280|INFO|Call Begin Header
>      ==============================================

If you want grouping of all log-messages belonging to an individual request with a single header. Then I think you should create a log-viewer (maybe web-based) that can provide grouping of log-message based on requestid/correlationid.

Comment: Problem with this solution is if the user only wants errors the line will not be displayed. I want it always to appear, but dont want to label it as error or fatal

Comment: @Narase You could just check if the `logger.IsEnabled(loglevel)` and only perform the header printing if loglevel is wanted. Make sure to print the header with the same loglevel as the actual logmessages.